# Get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Error from Linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error

here is my code:

```
    public ActionResult Profile(string id)
    {

            News_Application.NewsDatabaseEntities db = new News_Application.NewsDatabaseEntities();
            var result = (from u in db.AspNetUsers
                          where u.Id == id
                          select new { u.Id, u.WriterName, u.ProfilePicture }).FirstOrDefault();

            UserViewModel mo = new UserViewModel();

              mo.id = result.Id;
              mo.WriterName = result.WriterName;
              mo.WriterImage = result.ProfilePicture;


              return View(mo);
    }
```

Please help me. Thank you so much

Comment: Where? What's the stack trace? I note you're using `FirstOrDefault()`, which means if there are no matches, `result` will be `null`... but you're unconditionally dereferencing it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your LINQ query is giving you NULL for the where condition you have. But you are trying to access the property values of `result` without checking whether it is null or not

```
public ActionResult Profile(string id)
{
    var db = new News_Application.NewsDatabaseEntities();
    var result = (from u in db.AspNetUsers
                          where u.Id == id
                     select new { u.Id, u.WriterName, u.ProfilePicture }).FirstOrDefault();

    if(result==null)
    {
      return Content("No records matching the where condition");
     //to do : Change to a Not found view.
    }
    UserViewModel mo = new UserViewModel();

     mo.id = result.Id;
     mo.WriterName = result.WriterName;
     mo.WriterImage = result.ProfilePicture;

     return View(mo);
}
```

Also you may project your result to the UserViewModel and make it more simple/short

```
var users=db.AspNetUsers.Where(s=>sId==id)
                 .Select(x=> new UserViewModel { Id=x.Id,
                                                 WriterImage =x.ProfileImage, 
                                                 WriterName=x.WriteName}).ToList();
 if(users.Any())
 {
   return View(users.First());
 }
 return Content("User not found");
```

Comment: I tried your code and it's working after i put if(result==null) but it didn't tell me No records matching the where condition while the same code told me before i put  if(result==null) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.... the question is how to avoid that problem again?

Thank you so much